# How can you set the selected item in an ASP.NET dropdown via the display text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET dropdown that I've filled via databinding. I have the text that matches the display text for the listitem I want to be selected. I obviously can't use SelectedText (getter only) and I don't know the index, so I can't use SelectedIndex. I currently am selecting the item by iterating through the entire list, as show below:

ASP:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddItems" runat="server" />
```

Code:

```
ddItems.DataSource = myItemCollection;
ddItems.DataTextField = "Name";
ddItems.DataValueField = "Id";

foreach (ListItem item in ddItems.Items)
{
    if (item.Text == textToSelect)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without iterating through all the items?

Comment: This might be a simple/stupid question, but I'm fairly new to ASP webforms.

Comment: definitely not simple or stupid. @kbrimington has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can try:

```
ddItems.Items.FindByText("Hello, World!").Selected = true;
```

Or:

```
ddItems.SelectedValue = ddItems.Items.FindByText("Hello, World!").Value;
```

Note that, if you are not certain that an items exists matching your display text, you may need to check the results of `FindByText()` for `null`.

Note that I use the first approach on a multiple-select list, such as a `CheckBoxList` to add an additional selection. I use the second approach to override all selections.

Comment: you beat me to it.  I use the first option.

Comment: the null reference check should be used on either of those options. You can't guarantee the text will be there.

Comment: @rock: Thanks for your response. I added a note explaining when I would choose one over the other.

Comment: @KP: Thanks. I had made mention of that already, but left it out for clarity. Besides, there exist cases where you can guarantee text exists and save a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks! Quick answer and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FindByText` method of the `ListItemCollection` class, such as:

```
ListItem itemToSelect = ddlItems.Items.FindByText("some text to match");

if(itemToSelect != null)
{
    itemToSelect.Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to select dropdown selected item text for multiple dropdown cases then use this way.

```
// Call Method
SelectDropdownItemByText(ddlDropdown.Items.FindByText("test"));

// Define method
public void SelectDropdownItemByText(ListItem item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its working fine ..

```
drplistcountry.SelectedIndex = 
drplistcountry.Items.IndexOf(drplistcountry.Items.FindByText("--Select--"));
```

Or

```
drplistcountry.ClearSelection();
drplistcountry.SelectedIndex = 
drplistcountry.Items.IndexOf(drplistcountry.Items.FindByText("--Select--"));
```