# Can't set dropdown list selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I have a `DropDown` list on an ASP.Net web page. I'm trying to set its SelectedValue` on page load. I'm using [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587341/how-can-you-set-the-selected-item-in-an-asp-net-dropdown-via-the-display-text) as a reference. Here's my code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlType" DataSourceID="sdsType" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="AssetTypeID" />
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsType" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SystemManagement %>' SelectCommand="SELECT AssetTypeID, [Name] FROM AssetType UNION SELECT 0, '' ORDER BY [Name]" SelectCommandType="Text" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["searchtype"] != null)
        {
            ddlType.SelectedValue = ddlType.Items.FindByText(Request.QueryString["searchtype"]).Value;
            ddlType.SelectedValue = "1";
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

The first line that sets the `SelectedValue` will give me a Null Reference Exception and if I inspect the `ddlType` it has no Items. However, if I comment out the first line setting the `SelectedValue` and set it using the second line (just hard coding the value) it works. What's going on?

Comment: have you set breakpoints and used the debugger..? does it jump into the if(Request line try using just this line of code to find the value in the dropdown based off the value of the Request.QueryStringtring value
`ddlType.Items.FindByText(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["searchtype"])).Selected= true;`

Comment: you don't need then line if what I posted in previous comment works `ddlType.SelectedValue = "1";`

Comment: I've used the debugger and the querystring is what I expect it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `OnDataBound` event to do your current logic

```
/*Note the addition of "OnDataBound" */
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                  ID="ddlType" 
                  DataSourceID="sdsType" 
                  DataTextField="Name" 
                  DataValueField="AssetTypeID"
                  OnDataBound="ddlType_DataBound"                 
/>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsType" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SystemManagement %>' SelectCommand="SELECT AssetTypeID, [Name] FROM AssetType UNION SELECT 0, '' ORDER BY [Name]" SelectCommandType="Text" />

protected void ddlType_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["searchtype"] != null)
        {
            ddlType.SelectedValue = ddlType.Items.FindByText(Request.QueryString["searchtype"]).Value;
            ddlType.SelectedValue = "1";
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Jon P, although I decided to go with Tasos K's solution, yours works just as well, so I've upvoted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to set the value for `ddlType`, the `DataSource` is not yet loaded to the `DropDown`. If you check the debugger, the `ddlType.Items` property will show you that it currently has no items, which explains the NullReference exception.

Try to call `ddlType.DataBind()` before to ensure that `ddlType.Items` has the items from the database.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlType.DataBind(); // Load data from DataSource
        if (Request.QueryString["searchtype"] != null)
        {
            ddlType.SelectedValue = ddlType.Items.FindByText(Request.QueryString["searchtype"]).Value;
            ddlType.SelectedValue = "1";
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Make sure to have the `ddlType.DataBind()` inside the `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` condition, to avoid loading the data from the database on every PostBack.

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much Tasos K!